# How to trim X% top and bottom of a data frame (based on a column)?

Tags: r, sorting, data-cleaning, trim

I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(3994)
val <- round(runif(n=30, min = 5, max= 300), digits=0)
cat <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each= 10)
date <- as.Date(sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 30))

df <- data.frame(val, cat, date)
df <- df %>%  
  arrange(cat, val)
```

I want to trim top X% and bottom X% of my data for each category based on column `cat`. For example I want to remove top  2% and bottom 2% for category "A", "B", and "C". When the data is sorted based on `val` column.

I wrote the following code:

```
trimTopBottomByCategory <- function(dataframe, category_col, numeric_col, date_column,  x) {
  trimmed_dataframes <- list()
  
  categories <- unique(dataframe[[category_col]])
  for (category in categories) {
    subset_df <- dataframe[dataframe[[category_col]] == category, ]
    
    n <- nrow(subset_df)
    num_to_trim <- ceiling(x / 100 * n)
    
    sorted_subset <- subset_df[order(subset_df[[numeric_col]]), ]
    trimmed_df <- sorted_subset[(num_to_trim + 1):(n - num_to_trim), ]
    trimmed_dataframes[[category]] <- trimmed_df
  }

  trimmed_combined <- do.call(rbind, trimmed_dataframes)
  return(trimmed_combined <- trimmed_combined %>% 
             arrange(category_col, date_column))
}
```

**My Question:** I hope my code is doing what it is supposed to. But I was wondering if there is a method in R that does the same?

**Bonus Question:** I don't understand my final data is not sorted for the `date` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` by *cat* and *data* rather than by *cat* and *val*. (Should also work with `dplyr::arrange`, but I don't want to load `dplyr`.)

```
df <- df[with(df, order(cat, date)), ]
```

You can use `ave`, where first argument is value *val*, and second is the category *cat*. `ave` applies `FUN` to the values in each category. To get the highest and lowest 2% we can use `quantile`, and compare the values subsequently. Actually it's boolean, but due to `val` is numeric we get numeric back, so we use `as.logical` to get desired boolean, with which we can generate `ss` to subset the data frame.

```
ss <- with(df, as.logical(ave(val, cat, FUN=\(x) {
  q <- quantile(x, probs=c(.02, 1 - .02))
  x >= q[1] & x <= q[2]
})))

df[ss, ]
#    val cat       date
# 3   81   A 2000-08-10
# 10 188   A 2000-11-03
# 4  171   A 2006-11-26
# 2  182   A 2009-07-05
# 7  173   A 2010-09-12
# 6   54   A 2012-06-01
# 1  227   A 2014-08-05
# 9   95   A 2016-09-13
# 17 219   B 2002-12-29
# 14 221   B 2004-07-28
# 18 225   B 2011-06-29
# 19 191   B 2013-03-05
# 16 236   B 2013-09-27
# 12 117   B 2015-11-30
# 15 131   B 2017-11-22
# 13  92   B 2019-02-09
# 27 251   C 2000-03-13
# 30 160   C 2001-03-12
# 28 112   C 2002-02-19
# 29 174   C 2005-07-19
# 22 248   C 2006-12-23
# 21 176   C 2012-01-25
# 26  85   C 2016-08-06
# 24  56   C 2017-12-12
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(val = c(81, 188, 171, 12, 264, 182, 173, 54, 227, 
95, 219, 221, 274, 78, 225, 191, 236, 117, 131, 92, 251, 160, 
112, 265, 174, 248, 176, 42, 85, 56), cat = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C"), date = structure(c(11179, 11264, 13478, 13910, 14119, 14430, 
14864, 15492, 16287, 17057, 12050, 12627, 14565, 14605, 15154, 
15769, 15975, 16769, 17492, 17936, 11029, 11393, 11737, 12467, 
12983, 13505, 15364, 15472, 17019, 17512), class = "Date")), row.names = c(3L, 
10L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 17L, 14L, 20L, 11L, 18L, 
19L, 16L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 27L, 30L, 28L, 23L, 29L, 22L, 21L, 25L, 
26L, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr option:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(cat) %>%
mutate(proc = (row_number()-1)/(n()-1)*100) %>% #modify here if you need to adjust code 
# for instance to remove rows by value not row_number order use rank()
filter(between(proc, 2, 98)) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-proc) %>%
arrange(date)
```