# Why filter() doesn't work properly when there are multiple categories in one column?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(3994)
val <- seq(1:60)
cat <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times=c(30, 20, 10))
date <- as.Date(sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 60))

df <- data.frame(val, cat, date)
df <- df %>%  
  arrange(cat, val)
```

I want to remove the top and bottom x percent of the data for each category (when data is sorted). For instance, top 2% and bottom 2% of category "A","B" and "C". I have the following code:

```
remove_percentile_by_category <- function(data, measurement_column, category_column, date_column, percent_to_remove) {
  # Sort the data by category and measurement (assuming it's already sorted by category)
  data_sorted <- data %>%
    arrange({{category_column}}, {{measurement_column}})

  # Calculate the number of rows for each category
  summary_data <- data_sorted %>%
    group_by({{category_column}}) %>%
    summarize(n = n())
  print(n)
  # Calculate the number of rows to remove for each category
  summary_data <- summary_data %>%
    mutate(
      n_to_remove = ceiling(n * percent_to_remove / 100)
    )
  print(summary_data)
  # Remove the top and bottom rows for each category
  data_filtered <- data_sorted %>%
    group_by({{category_column}}) %>%
    filter(row_number() > summary_data$n_to_remove & row_number() <= n() - summary_data$n_to_remove) %>%
    ungroup()

  return(data_filtered %>%
           arrange({{category_column}}, {{date_column}}))
}
```

I know that the calculation of the number of rows to be deleted is correct, but when it comes to the following line of code, the issue happens.

```
filter(row_number() > summary_data$n_to_remove & row_number() <= n() - summary_data$n_to_remove)
```

**Question:** The above line of code doesn't assign the correct `n_to_remove` to each category. For example, it should remove the top and bottom 2 rows (4 rows total) of category `A`, instead, it only removes one row from top and bottom (2 rows total). What am I doing wrong?

PS. I have already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248089/how-to-trim-x-top-and-bottom-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-column/77248570#77248570). The solution provided for that question is correct, but gives me some weird errors due to my data structure. I gave up on that solution and also my original code provided in that question. I developed this new code which works fine with my data, but it doesn't correctly accomplish its intended task. Any help much be much appreciated.

Comment: I havent spent any time looking at your issue and code in detail, I immediately noticed a 'code smell' which is the mix of base R style syntax in a tidyverse context, in likely a breaking way. if you filter or mutate a frame, the filter and mutate knows what frame you are working on and variables within it that you access wont need the `$` signifier to pointlessly repeat the source name; furthermore if you have an issue where the filter or mutate must be influenced by foreign data, this would likely still not justify such useage

Comment: , rather a more explicit prior step of deciding on an appropriate data join (full,left,right,inner, cross) would be idiomatic and best practice. unless you are expert and can confidently break the rules due to your level of knowledge as to why in your particular case you would be safe and justified. If I'm way off, let me know, I might look later, but I would wager this is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach to make your code work which avoids creating any additional dataframes:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
remove_percentile_by_category <- function(data,
                                          measurement_column,
                                          category_column,
                                          date_column,
                                          percent_to_remove) {
  data %>%
    arrange({{ category_column }}, {{ measurement_column }}) %>%
    add_count({{ category_column }}) %>%
    mutate(n_to_remove = ceiling(n * percent_to_remove / 100)) %>%
    filter(row_number() > n_to_remove,
      row_number() <= n() - n_to_remove,
      .by = {{ category_column }}
    ) %>%
    select(-n, -n_to_remove)
}

count(df, cat)
#>   cat  n
#> 1   A 30
#> 2   B 20
#> 3   C 10
df_filtered <- remove_percentile_by_category(df, val, cat, percent_to_remove = 10)
count(df_filtered, cat)
#>   cat  n
#> 1   A 24
#> 2   B 16
#> 3   C  8
```